# SSRS Dynamic Pivot Format Columns

Tags: reporting-services, pivot

I have a report that uses the Matrix to create a pivot on my data. The data looks like this

[image]

The report looks like this

[image]

The pivot is on the Question column. When I export this report to excel I want the columns with Score to format as number and not as text. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can click on your matrix the specific cell and format values. Number with desired set or decimal precision is an option. Let me know if you cannot easy find it. I can put a scree shot.

Comment: The columns are all dynamic. So I cannot set it at design time. Look at the data in my post above. Each question becomes a column in the final output.

Comment: try enforcing by inserting the final result set into a temp table or variable and explicitly declaring all the data-types esp for numeric fields how your like be [int], [float], decimal 10,2 etc. Because at the end of day ssrs is going to evaluate your proc and get the meta-data from that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need calculate in Excel, just want to show number in right of cell(text is show in left), you could use expression like below in TextAlign properties(=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!answer.Value), "Right","Left"))

[image]

And other workaround is that you could change this in Excel (click cell to change type manually)

Zoe

Answer (score 0):

do make sure to do this to each cell. Once you do it to one cell; you can go down to properties window towards the bottom right and look for 'Format' property; the actual format value should be stored there. That way you can just copy paste the format on desired cells.
[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP is using a matrix. I thought using an expression to control the format might work (like `=IIF(ISNUMERIC(Fields!Answer.Value), "f1", nothing)`) but when you export to excel it sets the values as text as they are mixed types within a column. I think this might just be a limitation of the Excel renderer.. I'd love to be wrong though..

Comment: @AlanSchofield yes that is the precisely the issue here, It also doesn't help that there are header rows (about 3) that have multiple cells merged as one and that also is preventing it from formatting those columns as number